# Textarea Value as URL Hash Encode Base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a tool I'm building for writing blog posts. I was wondering if it is possible to take the value of a textarea -> encode with base64 -> set as URL hash without refresh.

The values should be equal between the textarea and hash. If one updates then so does the other. That way all the client has to do is share the URL and the textarea will load.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that there's a limit on the number of characters you can have in your URL. Blog posts can be pretty long, so you're likely to run into that limit. Here's a relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Also, base64 encoded strings are longer than their originals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) method to base64 encode a string. From there you can simply update the fragment of the URL using `window.location.hash`. Try this:

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  var encodedValue = btoa(this.value);
  window.location.hash = encodedValue;
  
  $('div').text(encodedValue); // only to show the encoded output in this demo
});
```

```css
textarea { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>

<div></div>
```

Note that `btoa()` is unsupported in < IE10 so if you need to support legacy browsers you will need an alternative implementation. There are lots already available if you Google.